# how to increase iframe height when tab selected containts long content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, yii

I have included iframe to other web page as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.addEventListener("message", function(e){var $iframe=document.getElementById("my-iframe"); var eventName=e.data[0]; var data=e.data[1];switch(eventName){case "setHeight": $iframe.height=parseInt(data); break; case "scrollToTop": $iframe.scrollIntoView(); break;}}, false);
</script>

<div style="width:100%; text-align:left;" >
<iframe src="http://mywebpage.com/list?mode=iframe" frameborder="0" height="1000" width="100%" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginheight="5" marginwidth="5" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" id="my-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have three tabs in iframe page, first tab contains data which don't have long content but third tab having long content.
When i open third tab, iframe height doesn't get increased. Iframe height remains same when loaded for first time and remaining page's content gets hidden.
How can i fix this ?
I have used  TBHTML tabs for tab rendering as below.

```
echo TbHtml::tabbableTabs($tabs);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe-resizer jquery plugin to overcome this issue

http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/

example

http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/example/

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use following code

```
document.getElementById("my-iframe").height = (document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight) + 'px';
```